# Backed up text messages are duplicated after Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sms, backup

I backed up my text messages to OneDrive before upgrading to Windows 10. Now all of the backed up messaged are being displayed twice. This does not happen for messaged received after the update.

I believe this is happening independent of the Windows 10 update. These messages are also saved onto my SD card, which was not inserted during the update. My first thought was to delete them from the SD card but I could not find where they are located. Turning off text message backup also did not help. Of course, I don't want to delete all of these messages manually.

How can I delete these duplicates and only keep one copy?

[image]

Comment: I faced a similar problem when resetting my Windows phone 8.1. All my contacts were duplicated too. I disconnected my Microsoft account, deleted all contacts and messages and reconnected my MS account. Try this and let us know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I faced a similar problem yesterday whe i upgraded to WIndows 10 Mobile.